# Ethernet connection keeps dropping out

Tags: networking, ethernet, diagnostic

I'm having a problem with my Ethernet connection dropping out. In games like destiny 2 and new world where if your net drops out (even with wifi as backup) you get kicked from the instance, which is very inconvenient.

When it drops out sometimes it takes around 5 minutes to come back, other times it will drop out for 30sec then come back for a minute then drop out again. No one else on the net is doing anything besides streaming TV in 1080p or browsing on their phones. During the times when the ethernet connection drops out wifi still works. I have no issues with the wifi. There is at most 3 users on the network at one time.

Things i've tried:

1. Different Ethernet cable
2. Deleting drivers and re-installing them
3. Updating BIOS
4. Different router
5. Resetting router
6. Updating router firmware
7. Run through every troubleshooting step i could find on google e.g. network troubleshooter, power management settings etc.
8. I've used the same cable on another computer to confirm its not the cable.

I'm starting to think its the motherboard, but before i buy a new one i want make sure i've exhausted every other option.

Hardware:

- Ryzen 7 3700x
- Asrock x570 Phantom Gaming 4
- Corsair H100i
- Corsair vengeance 2x16gb DDR4 3200 mhz
- RTX 2070 Windforce 8gb
- Corsair rm1000x power supply
- Curcial 1tb m.2 ssd for OS

Comment: Try a USB Ethernet adapter.  If this works, it is likely the adapter on the motherboard that is the issue.

Comment: Do you have Cable or DSL?

Comment: @Ramhound i got fiber to the premises FTTP

Comment: what brand/model is the onboard ethernet on that motherboard? You could always buy a PCIe ethernet adapter, they're dirt cheap

Comment: I have a friend who had a similar problem they were using the ISP supplied modem for their fiber to installation. The minute they purchased a reasonably priced high end router the problem went away.

Comment: @Ramhound I had the issue with the ISP modem and a netgear modem i bought

Comment: Had or have? Important distinction